# How to put "second" text in front of the first

Tags: html, css

[image]
How can i do something like that? I've tried tables but didn't work. Always stays like

```
Maniac - Last Seen:
Whiteout - Last Seen:
```

and I would like

```
Maniac   - Last Seen:
Whiteout - Last Seen:
```

Comment: You can use css-grids, table, flex or define first text width

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question showing us what you've tried please

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it with css grid:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
}

.grid-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 120px 10px 1fr;
}

.grid-row span:first-child {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-row">
    <span>Maniac</span><span>-</span><span>Last Seen:</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-row">
   <span>SOme long text here SOme long text here</span><span>-</span><span>Last Seen:</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or if you want to cut long text:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
}

.grid-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 120px 10px 1fr;
}

.grid-row span:first-child {
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap; 
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-row">
    <span>Maniac</span><span>-</span><span>Last Seen:</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-row">
   <span>SOme long text here SOme long text here</span><span>-</span><span>Last Seen:</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!